# RecyclerView drag-drop - using ItemTouchHelper - How to set scrolling speed faster while dragging?

Tags: android, scroll, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I tried this code for drag and drop : https://github.com/iPaulPro/Android-ItemTouchHelper-Demo.

Here is a video : https://youtu.be/lMsv2jYpbi4

Is there a way to speed up the scrolling during drag-and-drop ?

Answer (score 20):

In your class that extends `ItemTouchHelper.Callback`, override the method:

```
@Override
public int interpolateOutOfBoundsScroll(RecyclerView recyclerView, int viewSize, int viewSizeOutOfBounds, int totalSize, long msSinceStartScroll) {
    final int direction = (int) Math.signum(viewSizeOutOfBounds);
    return 10 * direction;
}
```

This is a simple example which uses a fixed scroll speed, but if you wanted something that started slow and sped up (like the `super.interpolateOutOfBoundsScroll` does) you can do some maths based on the time since scrolling (`msSinceStartScroll`) and also the position in the overall scroll (example scroll faster when in the middle of the scroller and slower when you near the start/end).